# Only show number buttons on Soft Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

On the soft keyboard in Android you can set the soft keyboard to show the numbers instead of a-z keyboard using `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`. However, what do I do if I only want to show the top number row `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` and not the following rows starting with `@ # $ % ...`?

Thanx for listening!

Comment: You cab see my answer on below question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Comment: @AndroidHelp The question was posted six years ago, and it was solved four years ago. Today I don't develop apps for Android. I've moved on to work with SharePoint :)

Comment: isnt there an answer to this yet? Like an inbuilt keyboard by android yet?

Comment: it's depend on the third-part keyboard app thats user use you can only tell the softkey what type of data you want to using  android:inputType

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You must only add this line on your code:

```
input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

this will show **only** the numeric keyboard.

Comment: Nice! When the question was asked - this wasn't available. However this is what you're supposed to do today. Thanx!

Answer (score 67):

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="1234567890"
```

is an option

Comment: The next button on the soft keyboard goes away from this.

Answer (score 11):

The phone number pad is the closest thing I've found (set `inputType="phone"` on your `EditText`).

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me (tested on OnePlus 3t and Samsung Galaxy S6/S7 phones).

This solution uses numberPassword but overrides the default transformation method for the EditText to show characters instead of showing dots.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userid"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="6"
/>

// Numeric 6 character user id
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.userid);

// Process input and show characters instead of dots
input.setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 3):

Just posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897883/1672231) but re-posting for simplicity:

Seems Android has added the functionality we were seeking. This is the xml I use for simple EditText numeric entry:

```
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: This makes the text turn into a password, hiding the previously entered numbers.

Comment: Quite so. I don't know why G doesn't offer the 10-key to be shown without the other characters but maybe for some developers, this is a good way to produce the reduced keyboard. Of course, if people don't mind a few extraneous characters, the inputType of "number" will do the trick. For a 10-key without the password style visibility, a custom keyboard is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. It kept showing other unwanted characters

I found a way to accomplish the behavior I wanted by changing the inputType to `numberPassword` and then disabling the password dots

```
textInput.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD
textInput.transformationMethod = SingleLineTransformationMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Last I looked into it, Android did not have any good options for that. I ended up having to write my own version of a soft keyboard-like user interface.

Comment: So in order to go for the lowest version used in the market as of today (1.5) - I need to write my own SoftKeyboard.java class then. That'll be a challange :-)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you did that? Coz I need exactly that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented this for android in Xamarin. So, my code is in C#. But the principal stays the same. You can set attribute of edittext to `android:inputType="numberPassword"`.

Then within your code you attach custom transformation method to your edittext view.

```
holder.edtxtQty.TransformationMethod = new HiddenPasswordTransformationMethod();

private class HiddenPasswordTransformationMethod : global::Android.Text.Method.PasswordTransformationMethod
        {
            public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetTransformationFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, View view)
            {
                return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
            }
        }

    private class PasswordCharSequence : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.ICharSequence
    {
        private char DOT = '\u2022';

        private Java.Lang.ICharSequence _source;
        public PasswordCharSequence(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source)
        {
            _source = source;
        }

        public char CharAt(int index)
        {
            return _source.CharAt(index);
        }

        public int Length()
        {
            return _source.Length();
        }

        public Java.Lang.ICharSequence SubSequenceFormatted(int start, int end)
        {
            return _source.SubSequenceFormatted(start, end); // Return default
        }

        public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _source.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _source.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From code:

```
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```