# Is there a way to get an Android soft keyboard that has only numbers (no decimals, spaces) with Java code?

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse, android-softkeyboard

I have an iPhone app that uses different keyboard layouts. Some are custom and some are built in:

Numbers only:

[image: Numbers only]

Decimals:

[image: Decimals]

Custom X button for ISBN numbers:

[image: Custom X button for ISBN numbers]

I'd like to do the same thing on Android, but even the normal `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` still includes a decimals, space, comma, etc.

[image: Android]

How can I customize the keyboards in Android??

Comment: see this post maybe helpful for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible using the built-in keyboard. You'll have to develop a custom soft keyboard, or write an inline view that works like a keyboard replacement.

Comment: isnt there any inbuilt keyboard in android now? I want to show a keyboard with 0-9 with delete and enter buttons.

Answer (score 4):

I think this question has already been answered on StackOverflow.  Look at this:

[Only show number buttons on Soft Keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357302/only-show-number-buttons-on-soft-keyboard-in-android?rq=1)

@twaddington is correct that what you are asking for won't be possible with the built-in keyboard.  One thing you can do to prevent non-digits from being entered is set the following in XML for your `EditText`.

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="1234567890"
```

If you want to this in code, and not in XML, I think this should work:

```
numericField.setInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
numericField.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener());
```

To develop your own numeric soft keyboard, this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use inputType = "number", then you will get only number keypad.

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I hope it will help you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Use

```
numericField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

It anticipates number pad only on Holo, and backward compatible number pad on lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Android has added the functionality we were seeking. This is the xml I use for simple EditText numeric entry:

```
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ems="4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
```