# how to open numeric keypad automatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open numeric keyboard when click on EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839333/how-to-open-numeric-keyboard-when-click-on-edittext)

I have an activity with 4 `EditText` to enter digits. I have already changed their types to numbers in its layout, but chars soft-keyboard shows up.  How can I show the numeric keyboard when the activity starts?

Do any one have solution for this?
thank you.

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13839333/1056359

Comment: set input type as number in xml

Answer (score 4):

hey you might added the below line in EditText xml

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

if so remove and add the below line in the xml it works fine

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Check once, as per you question that might be the only problem. if you inputType = number then it never opens alphabets keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput((editText), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just inputType = "number" in xml layout file:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width = "..."
android:layout_heigth = "..."
...
android:inputType = "number"/>
```