# Need number only soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, android-input-method, qwerty

Hi I need a soft keyboard with only numeric values <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Shouldn't show anything other than these like <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> etc...

[image]

I tried several options [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357302/only-show-number-buttons-on-soft-keyboard-in-android) but nothings seems to work for me.

1. `setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY)`
2. `setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)`
3. `setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`
4. `setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE)`

I always have the extra characters show up on the keyboard like:

[image]

`setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY)` shows a keyboard like this:

[image]

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

NOTE:

- `android:minSdkVersion="14"`: ICS4.0
- `android:targetSdkVersion="17"`: JB 4.2

Comment: What does setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY) give you?

Comment: Post updated with screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can do for standard keyboards is suggest input types. The keyboard can still display or not display whatever keys it wants. If you *must* have certain keys and only those, you need to create a custom soft keyboard. If it's only for your app, and especially if it's only for one activity, I wouldn't actually implement a standard keyboard, but just use views/buttons that do the appropriate actions.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem , and i found tat there is no android keyboard like this available
and that the only way is to implement your own.
so i would like to share with you my implement and hopefully save you some valuable time:

1. i've created this xml , you can modify the colors,fonts and the size of the keyboard accourding to your needs:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="300dp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/one_to_three"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="3" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/one_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="1"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/two_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="2"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/three_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="3"
           android:textSize="25sp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/four_to_six"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/one_to_three"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="3" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/four_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="4"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/five_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="5"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/six_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="6"
           android:textSize="25sp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/seven_to_nine"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/four_to_six"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="3" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/seven_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="7"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/eight_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="8"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/nine_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="9"
           android:textSize="25sp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/zero"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/seven_to_nine"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="3" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/zero_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:text="0"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/back_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Back"
           android:textSize="25sp" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/done"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/zero"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/done_btn"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="Done"
           android:textSize="30sp" />
      </LinearLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
   ```

[image]

2. i've created this fragment:

   ```
           package com.galrom.keyboard; //replace it with your package
           import com.example.calculator.R;//import your own R class
           import android.app.Activity;
           import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
           import android.util.Log;
           import android.view.LayoutInflater;
           import android.view.View;
           import android.view.ViewGroup;
           import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
           import android.widget.Button;
           public class KeyBoardFragment extends Fragment {

           private Button one_btn;
           private Button two_btn;
           private Button three_btn;
           private Button four_btn;
           private Button five_btn;
           private Button six_btn;
           private Button seven_btn;
           private Button eight_btn;
           private Button nine_btn;
           private Button zero_btn;
           private Button back_btn;
           private Button done_btn;

           private StringBuilder sb;

           private onKeyBoardEvent keyboardEventListener;


           private int maxLength=10;
           private int currentLength;

           public static KeyBoardFragment newInstance(String EditTextValue)
           {
               KeyBoardFragment fragment=new KeyBoardFragment();
               Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
               bundle.putString("et_value", EditTextValue);
               fragment.setArguments(bundle);
               return fragment;
           }

           @Override
           public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
               try{

                   keyboardEventListener=(onKeyBoardEvent)activity;
               }
               catch(ClassCastException e)
               {
                   Log.e("ClassCastException in KeyBoardFragment row 50",activity.toString()+" must implement onKeyboardEvent");
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               super.onAttach(activity);
           }

           @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               sb=new StringBuilder(getArguments().getString("et_value"));
               currentLength=sb.length();
               View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.numeric_keyboard_layout, container, false);
               one_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.one_btn);
               one_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       add("1");
                   }
               });
               two_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.two_btn);
               two_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("2");
                   }
               });
               three_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.three_btn);
               three_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("3");

                   }
               });
               four_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.four_btn);
               four_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("4");
                   }
               });
               five_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.five_btn);
               five_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("5");

                   }
               });
               six_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.six_btn);
               six_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {


                       add("6");
                   }
               });
               seven_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.seven_btn);
               seven_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("7");
                   }
               });
               eight_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.eight_btn);
               eight_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("8");

                   }
               });
               nine_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nine_btn);
               nine_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       add("9");
                   }
               });
               zero_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.zero_btn);
               zero_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       if(sb.length()>0)
                           add("0");
                   }
               });
               back_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
               back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       if(sb.length()>0)
                       {
                           currentLength--;
                           sb.deleteCharAt((sb.length())-1);
                           keyboardEventListener.backButtonPressed(sb.toString());
                       }
                   }
               });
               back_btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                       currentLength=0;
                       sb=new StringBuilder();
                       keyboardEventListener.backLongPressed();
                       return false;
                   }
               });
               done_btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.done_btn);
               done_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       keyboardEventListener.doneButtonPressed(sb.toString());
                   }
               });
               return rootView;
           }
           public interface onKeyBoardEvent
           {
               public void numberIsPressed(String total);
               public void doneButtonPressed(String total);
               public void backLongPressed();
               public void backButtonPressed(String total);
           }

           public int getMaxLength() {
               return maxLength;
           }

           public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
               this.maxLength = maxLength;
           }
           public void add(String num)
           {
               currentLength++;
               if(currentLength<=maxLength)
               {

                   sb.append(num);
                   keyboardEventListener.numberIsPressed(sb.toString());
               }
               else
                   currentLength--;
           }
       }
   ```

3.the effect of a poping keyboard under the EditText when it is pressed is achived by
creating an empty RelativeLayout that function as an container to the keyboard:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.galrom.keyboard.EditTextNoKeyBoard
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Key_board_container"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Key_board_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

when the user press on the EditText the we add the fragment to the container and when he presses done we hide it. the keyboard fragment comunicate with the Activity with the onKeyBoardEvent interace.
NOTE:the hosting activity must implement this interface or else a ClassCastException will be thown.

VERY IMPORTANT: i didn't handled the orientation change, if you change to ladscape while the keyboard is open it will crash, so either disable landscape mode or handle the orientation change to avoid a nullPointerException on the key_board_fragment.

this is the Activity that implemets the keyBoard:

```
     package com.galrom.keyboard;

     import com.example.calculator.R;

     import android.content.res.Configuration;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements               KeyBoardFragment.onKeyBoardEvent{

private EditText et;
private KeyBoardFragment keyboard_fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyboard_fragment==null)
            {
                keyboard_fragment=KeyBoardFragment.newInstance(et.getText().toString());

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.Key_board_container, keyboard_fragment).commit();


            }
            else
            {
                if(keyboard_fragment.isVisible())
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(keyboard_fragment).commit();
                else
                {
                    keyboard_fragment=KeyBoardFragment.newInstance(et.getText().toString());
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.Key_board_container, keyboard_fragment).commit();
                }
            }
    });
}

@Override
public void numberIsPressed(String total) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et.setText(total);
}

@Override
public void doneButtonPressed(String total) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et.setText(total);
    if(keyboard_fragment.isVisible())
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(keyboard_fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void backLongPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et.setText("");
}

@Override
public void backButtonPressed(String total) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    et.setText(total);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyboard_fragment!=null)
    {
        if(keyboard_fragment.isVisible())
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(keyboard_fragment).commit();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
       }
```

and the last thing:
to disable the poping of the standart keyboard of android i've created an CustomEditText that simply returns false at: onCheckIsTextEditor() , this is the CustomEditText class:

```
 package com.galrom.keyboard;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class EditTextNoKeyBoard extends EditText {

public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


public EditTextNoKeyBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
    }
```

Hope it helped you out...
if you have suggestions for improvement i will be happy to hear.
Gal.

Comment: This qualifies for a blog post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to it set **inputType="phone"** on the EditText. That will open numeric pad keyboard once you start typing however it will include all extra characters related to the numbers. You would need to implement your own keyboard to keep only the numeric values.

Comment: I tried the inputType="phone" and as you mentioned it still showed those extra characters. I think custom keyboard is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses numberPassword by overriding the default transformation method for the EditText to show characters instead of dots.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userid"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="6"
/>
```

Add to OnCreate.

```
// Numeric 6 character user id
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.userid);

// Process input and show characters instead of dots
input.setTransformationMethod(SingleLineTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

[image: Numeric soft keyboard Image]

Answer (score 1):

By default based on your device, the keyboard shows the special characters too in number keyboard . specifying the Keyboard type for the Text field you can achieve the expected result,such as

```
 InputFieldName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

**i.e.**

If you need only number included with special characters,then you can use 
`InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`

**or**

if you need to exclude those special characters too  then use `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard itself chooses what keys to `layout`.  The best you can do is specify `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`, but the keyboard will still display whatever it thinks is appropriate to a numeric text field.

Comment: thank you. Can I mention the type of the input that can be expected in the edit text in the program?

Comment: The lock screens on all devices seems to have this number only keyboards. Any idea if these are system keyboard or custom built?

Comment: They're custom built.  You can always write your own custom keyboard, but it isn't really worth a lot of time.  For a numeric you may even be better off not making it a keyboard and acting as if its a giant calculator app.  I think that's what they do-  9 buttons in the layout for the keyboard, and manually insert text in the button's onClick.

Answer (score 0):

i have had the same problem that you have, and just came with a solution, perhaps its not elegant, nor its easy, but it does work splendid...

First of all, the only InputType that works with that keyboard (at least until 4.3) is "numberPassword", but this "hides" your input as dots. so i used that input with this transformation method:

```
    private class ShowNumbersTransformationMethod implements TransformationMethod {
    public CharSequence getTransformation(final CharSequence charSequence, final View view) {
        return new PassCharSequence(charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChanged(final View view, final CharSequence charSequence, final boolean b, final int i,
            final Rect rect) {
        //nothing to do here
    }

    private class PassCharSequence implements CharSequence {

        private final CharSequence charSequence;

        public PassCharSequence(final CharSequence charSequence) {
            this.charSequence = charSequence;
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(final int index) {
            return charSequence.charAt(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return charSequence.length();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(final int start, final int end) {
            return new PassCharSequence(charSequence.subSequence(start, end));
        }
    }
}
```

and then set it to your edittext:

```
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new ShowNumbersTransformationMethod());
```

Now, as said before, this is not the happiest solution, but i assure you it works like a charm. It would be 10 times easier to create your own custom keyboard, but, i didnt have that option, since my client wanted the standard keyboard, god knows why...

Hope it helped!

Comment: Setting numberPassword will make you loose your custom font for this component.