# Only Number keyboard in Android using Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, keyboard

I am asking the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357302/only-show-number-buttons-on-soft-keyboard-in-android) but the question is very old and I am wondering if there is any direct answer to this one.As I recently saw this in an app with this keyboard

[image]

Is this kind of keyboard available in android now. If yes how can I get it? I am using Cordova to get this kind of keyboard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose an <input type="number"> is not working ?

Comment: @YannickHelmut <input type="number"> gives me "," "." and space. which i dont want.

Comment: Then use `<input type="tel">` this supports android devices.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda yes but then again it shows me "+" "pause" etc. which i don't want. I want it to be exactly what's in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

accepted
You can get any kind of Keyboard when you tap an input depending on its type

For a numeric keyboard, you need to set its type to number

```
<input type="number" name="txtNumber"/>
```

Comment: <input type="number"> gives me "," "." and space. which i dont want.

Comment: you can use CSS

<input type="number" style="-webkit-text-security:disc">

Comment: I am already doing that buddy. Please understand my question. I want the keyboard to display "0-9" numbers, Enter button and delete button. Nothing else just like the screenshot i posted in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set pattern here

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*"/>
```

This will shows digits only.

Comment: Just tried it, still is same as type="number" and shows me "-" "," "." 
I don't want those characters.

Comment: If you see the screenshot it has only numbers from 0-9 , delete and enter. That's all i want to be there in the keyboard.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html) I found one link where, there are many different between iPhone and Android device to with the same line of code.

Comment: But the screenshot in OP is from an android device only. I want to replicate that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Checking for native android app keyboard types, will update here if found any related code which i can able implement from native to hybrid for this.